# Incorrect reference line in algorithmic and algorithm package. Everything is referenced as line number 1

Tags: amsmath, algorithms, cleveref, algorithmic

I am using `algorithm` and `algorithmic` package to write pseudocode of algorithm. But when I refer to labels defined inside the algorithm, it always says it's line `1`. I am at a loss to figure out how to fix this. For example, in the following example  `\ref{line:lambda}` would say `1`.

Here is my `sty` file.

```
% partial rewrite of the LaTeX2e package for submissions to the
% Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems (NeurIPS):
%
% - uses more LaTeX conventions
% - line numbers at submission time replaced with aligned numbers from
%   lineno package
% - \nipsfinalcopy replaced with [final] package option
% - automatically loads times package for authors
% - loads natbib automatically; this can be suppressed with the
%   [nonatbib] package option
% - adds foot line to first page identifying the conference
% - adds preprint option for submission to e.g. arXiv
% - conference acronym modified
%
% Roman Garnett (garnett@wustl.edu) and the many authors of
% nips15submit_e.sty, including MK and drstrip@sandia
%
% last revision: January 2020

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{neurips_2020}[2020/01/31 NeurIPS 2020 submission/camera-ready style file]

% declare final option, which creates camera-ready copy
\newif\if@neuripsfinal\@neuripsfinalfalse
\DeclareOption{final}{
  \@neuripsfinaltrue
}

% declare nonatbib option, which does not load natbib in case of
% package clash (users can pass options to natbib via
% \PassOptionsToPackage)
\newif\if@natbib\@natbibtrue
\DeclareOption{nonatbib}{
  \@natbibfalse
}

% declare preprint option, which creates a preprint version ready for
% upload to, e.g., arXiv
\newif\if@preprint\@preprintfalse
\DeclareOption{preprint}{
  \@preprinttrue
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% determine whether this is an anonymized submission
\newif\if@submission\@submissiontrue
\if@neuripsfinal\@submissionfalse\fi
\if@preprint\@submissionfalse\fi

% fonts
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

% change this every year for notice string at bottom
\newcommand{\@neuripsordinal}{34th}
\newcommand{\@neuripsyear}{2020}
\newcommand{\@neuripslocation}{Vancouver, Canada}

% acknowledgments
\usepackage{environ}
\newcommand{\acksection}{\section*{Acknowledgments and Disclosure of Funding}}
\NewEnviron{ack}{%
  \acksection
  \BODY
}

% handle tweaks for camera-ready copy vs. submission copy
\if@preprint
  \newcommand{\@noticestring}{%
    Preprint. Under review.%
  }
\else
  \if@neuripsfinal
    \newcommand{\@noticestring}{%
      \@neuripsordinal\/ Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems
      (NeurIPS \@neuripsyear), \@neuripslocation.%
    }
  \else
    \newcommand{\@noticestring}{%
      Submitted to \@neuripsordinal\/ Conference on Neural Information
      Processing Systems (NeurIPS \@neuripsyear). Do not distribute.%
    }

    % hide the acknowledgements
    \NewEnviron{hide}{}
    \let\ack\hide
    \let\endack\endhide

    % line numbers for submission
    \RequirePackage{lineno}
    \linenumbers

    % fix incompatibilities between lineno and amsmath, if required, by
    % transparently wrapping linenomath environments around amsmath
    % environments
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
        \newcommand*\patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno[1]{%
          \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
          \expandafter\let\csname oldend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
          \renewenvironment{#1}%
                           {\linenomath\csname old#1\endcsname}%
                           {\csname oldend#1\endcsname\endlinenomath}%
        }%
        \newcommand*\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno[1]{%
          \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1}%
          \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1*}%
        }%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{equation}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{align}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{flalign}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{alignat}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{gather}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{multline}%
      }{}
    }
  \fi
\fi

% load natbib unless told otherwise
\if@natbib
  \RequirePackage{natbib}
\fi

% set page geometry
\usepackage[verbose=true,letterpaper]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \newgeometry{
    textheight=9in,
    textwidth=5.5in,
    top=1in,
    headheight=12pt,
    headsep=25pt,
    footskip=30pt
  }
  \@ifpackageloaded{fullpage}
    {\PackageWarning{neurips_2020}{fullpage package not allowed! Overwriting formatting.}}
    {}
}

\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\flushbottom
\sloppy

% font sizes with reduced leading
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
  \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xipt
  \abovedisplayskip      7\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 5\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus 3\p@
  \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@
}
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\small}{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt\@xpt
  \abovedisplayskip      6\p@ \@plus 1.5\p@ \@minus 4\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@  \@plus 2\p@
  \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus 2\p@   \@minus 2\p@
}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt\@xpt}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\renewcommand{\tiny}{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\renewcommand{\large}{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{16}}
\renewcommand{\LARGE}{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{20}}
\renewcommand{\huge}{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{23}}
\renewcommand{\Huge}{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{28}}

% sections with less space
\providecommand{\section}{}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                {-2.0ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 1.5ex \@plus  0.3ex \@minus  0.2ex}%
                {\large\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\subsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                {-1.8ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 0.8ex \@plus  0.2ex}%
                {\normalsize\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\subsubsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                {-1.5ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 0.5ex \@plus  0.2ex}%
                {\normalsize\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\paragraph}{}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                {1.5ex \@plus 0.5ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalsize\bf}%
}
\providecommand{\subparagraph}{}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                {1.5ex \@plus 0.5ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalsize\bf}%
}
\providecommand{\subsubsubsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsubsection}{%
  \vskip5pt{\noindent\normalsize\rm\raggedright}%
}

% float placement
\renewcommand{\topfraction      }{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction   }{0.4}
\renewcommand{\textfraction     }{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}

\newlength{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}\setlength{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}{7\p@}
\newlength{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}\setlength{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}{\z@}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}

% swap above/belowcaptionskip lengths for tables
\renewenvironment{table}
  {\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@neuripsbelowcaptionskip}%
   \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@neuripsabovecaptionskip}%
   \@float{table}}
  {\end@float}

% footnote formatting
\setlength{\footnotesep }{6.65\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{9\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern-3\p@ \hrule width 12pc \kern 2.6\p@}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

% paragraph formatting
\setlength{\parindent}{\z@}
\setlength{\parskip  }{5.5\p@}

% list formatting
\setlength{\topsep       }{4\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength{\partopsep    }{1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\itemsep      }{2\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\parsep       }{2\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\leftmargin   }{3pc}
\setlength{\leftmargini  }{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\leftmarginii }{2em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiii}{1.5em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiv }{1.0em}
\setlength{\leftmarginv  }{0.5em}
\def\@listi  {\leftmargin\leftmargini}
\def\@listii {\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep  2\p@ \@plus 1\p@    \@minus 0.5\p@
              \parsep  1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep    1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \parsep    \z@
              \partopsep 0.5\p@ \@plus 0\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv {\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv  {\leftmargin\leftmarginv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi {\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
              \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

% create title
\providecommand{\maketitle}{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
    % for perfect author name centering
    \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox to \z@{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
    % The footnote-mark was overlapping the footnote-text,
    % added the following to fix this problem               (MK)
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
      \parindent 1em\noindent
      \hbox to 1.8em{\hss $\m@th ^{\@thefnmark}$}##1
    }
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \@maketitle
    \@thanks
    \@notice
  \endgroup
  \let\maketitle\relax
  \let\thanks\relax
}

% rules for title box at top of first page
\newcommand{\@toptitlebar}{
  \hrule height 4\p@
  \vskip 0.25in
  \vskip -\parskip%
}
\newcommand{\@bottomtitlebar}{
  \vskip 0.29in
  \vskip -\parskip
  \hrule height 1\p@
  \vskip 0.09in%
}

% create title (includes both anonymized and non-anonymized versions)
\providecommand{\@maketitle}{}
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \vbox{%
    \hsize\textwidth
    \linewidth\hsize
    \vskip 0.1in
    \@toptitlebar
    \centering
    {\LARGE\bf \@title\par}
    \@bottomtitlebar
    \if@submission
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}
        Anonymous Author(s) \\
        Affiliation \\
        Address \\
        \texttt{email} \\
      \end{tabular}%
    \else
      \def\And{%
        \end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[0]\hfil%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\ignorespaces%
      }
      \def\AND{%
        \end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[4]\hfil%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\ignorespaces%
      }
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\@author\end{tabular}%
    \fi
    \vskip 0.3in \@minus 0.1in
  }
}

% add conference notice to bottom of first page
\newcommand{\ftype@noticebox}{8}
\newcommand{\@notice}{%
  % give a bit of extra room back to authors on first page
  \enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}%
  \@float{noticebox}[b]%
    \footnotesize\@noticestring%
  \end@float%
}

% abstract styling
\renewenvironment{abstract}%
{%
  \vskip 0.075in%
  \centerline%
  {\large\bf Abstract}%
  \vspace{0.5ex}%
  \begin{quote}%
}
{
  \par%
  \end{quote}%
  \vskip 1ex%
}

% \endinput



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% haque added
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{bm} 
\RequirePackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{dsfont}





%%%%%%%%  amsmath %%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
    {\topsep}                    % Space above
    {\topsep}                    % Space below
    {\normalfont}                   % Body font
    {}                           % Indent amount
    {\bfseries}                   % Theorem head font
    {.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
    {}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\ifx\BlackBox\undefined
\newcommand{\BlackBox}{\rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}}  % end of proof
\fi

\ifx\QED\undefined
\def\QED{~\rule[-1pt]{5pt}{5pt}\par\medskip}
\fi

\ifx\proof\undefined
\newenvironment{proof}{\par\noindent{\bf Proof\ }}{\hfill\BlackBox\\[2mm]}
%\newenvironment{proof}{\emph{Proof. }}{ \hfill \QED}
\fi

\ifx\theorem\undefined
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\fi
\ifx\example\undefined
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\fi
\ifx\property\undefined
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\fi
\ifx\lemma\undefined
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\fi
\ifx\proposition\undefined
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\fi
\ifx\remark\undefined
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\fi
\ifx\corollary\undefined
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\fi
\ifx\definition\undefined
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\fi
\ifx\conjecture\undefined
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\fi
\ifx\fact\undefined
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\fi
\ifx\claim\undefined
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\fi
\ifx\assumption\undefined
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}
\fi
\ifx\cond\undefined
\newtheorem{cond}[theorem]{Condition}
\fi

\newtheoremstyle{anothertheoremstyle} % name
    {\topsep}                    % Space above
    {\topsep}                    % Space below
    {\normalfont}                   % Body font
    {}                           % Indent amount
    {\bfseries}                   % Theorem head font
    {.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
    {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} \normalfont{#3}}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\ifx\condition\undefined
\theoremstyle{anothertheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\fi
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}
\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother

\let\oldabstract\abstract
\let\oldendabstract\endabstract
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\renewenvironment{quotation}%
               {\list{}{\addtolength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % change this value to add or remove length to the the default
                       \listparindent 1em%
                        \itemindent    \listparindent%
                        \rightmargin   \leftmargin%
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}%
               {\endlist}%
\oldabstract}
{\oldendabstract}
\makeatother
```

Here is my `main.tex`

```
    \documentclass{article}

% if you need to pass options to natbib, use, e.g.:
%     \PassOptionsToPackage{numbers, compress}{natbib}
% before loading neurips_2020

% ready for submission
% \usepackage{neurips_2020}

% to compile a preprint version, e.g., for submission to arXiv, add add the
% [preprint] option:
%     \usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2020}

% to compile a camera-ready version, add the [final] option, e.g.:
%     \usepackage[final]{neurips_2020}

% to avoid loading the natbib package, add option nonatbib:
\usepackage[nonatbib]{neurips_2020}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography

%added by  

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{natbib}

% \usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox}
\usepackage{soul} %for strikethrough

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ALG@step}{\addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}}{\refstepcounter{ALG@line}}{}{}
\newcommand{\ALG@lineautorefname}{Line}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}

% \usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
% \usepackage{cleveref}

\hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=blue,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=cyan,
     }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\given{\,|\,}
\def\biggiven{\,\big{|}\,}
\def\Biggiven{\,\Big{|}\,}


\def\E{{\mathbb E}}
%equation with text "def" above
\newcommand\mydef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\newcommand{\red}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\la}{\langle}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}


\newtheorem{oracle}[theorem]{Oracle}


\title{Provably }


\author{%
  David S.~Hippocampus\thanks{Use footnote for providing further information
    about author (webpage, alternative address)---\emph{not} for acknowledging
    funding agencies.} \\
  Department of Computer Science\\
  Cranberry-Lemon University\\
  Pittsburgh, PA 15213 \\
  \texttt{hippo@cs.cranberry-lemon.edu} \\

}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Exploration}
\autoref{Alg}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{\label{Algorithm-T}RL}
% 
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\STATE Initialize. \label{line:winit}
\STATE \hspace{0.05in} \textbf{For} step {$t=1, 2, \ldots, H$} \textbf{do} \hfill (improvement) \label{line:pis-start}

\STATE \hspace{0.13in} Update $\pi^k_t $ \label{line:policy-improvement}
\STATE \hspace{0.15in}  Observe reward $r^k_{t}(\cdot)$.  \label{line:pis-end}

\STATE \hspace{0.13in} $\Sigma^k_t $.\label{line:lambda}\vspace{0.054in}
\STATE \hspace{0.13in} $\hat{\theta}$. \label{line:theta-hat}
\STATE \hspace{0.13in} .\vspace{0.054in}\label{line:pes-end}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Here \ref{line:lambda} would say $1$.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{references}




\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your example code, but I can't reproduce the issue - when I run the code the output is _Here 5 would say 1._ There was an error though with the contents of `\author`, I had to simplify that to make it work. Are you sure the issue you get is with this code, or does it only occur in your full document?

Comment: It's with full document. But not sure why it would happen with full document but not here.

Comment: Then you need to reduce your full document step by step (ie, remove LaTeX commands and contents) and check at every step if the issue still occurs. When it disappears then you know where the problem is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem can't be solved with the information presented in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a file named `algorithmic.sty` in the folder. Removing that solved the issue.

```
% ALGORITHMIC STYLE -- Released 8 APRIL 1996
%    for LaTeX version 2e
% Copyright -- 1994 Peter Williams
% E-mail PeterWilliams@dsto.defence.gov.au
%
% Modified by Alex Smola (08/2000)
% E-mail Alex.Smola@anu.edu.au
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{algorithmic}
\typeout{Document Style `algorithmic' - environment}
%
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\newboolean{ALC@noend}
\setboolean{ALC@noend}{false}
\newcounter{ALC@line}
\newcounter{ALC@rem}
\newlength{\ALC@tlm}
%
\DeclareOption{noend}{\setboolean{ALC@noend}{true}}
%
\ProcessOptions
%
% ALGORITHMIC
\newcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Require:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Ensure:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{end}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{if}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{then}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelse}{\textbf{else}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelsif}{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textbf{for}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for all}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\textbf{do}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendfor}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
\newcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{while}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendwhile}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}
\newcommand{\algorithmicloop}{\textbf{loop}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendloop}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicloop}
\newcommand{\algorithmicrepeat}{\textbf{repeat}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicuntil}{\textbf{until}}

%changed by alex smola
\newcommand{\algorithmicinput}{\textbf{input}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{output}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicset}{\textbf{set}}
\newcommand{\algorithmictrue}{\textbf{true}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicfalse}{\textbf{false}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{and\ }}
\newcommand{\algorithmicor}{\textbf{or\ }}
\newcommand{\algorithmicfunction}{\textbf{function}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendfunction}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}
\newcommand{\algorithmicmain}{\textbf{main}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendmain}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicmain}
%end changed by alex smola

\def\ALC@item[#1]{%
\if@noparitem \@donoparitem
  \else \if@inlabel \indent \par \fi
         \ifhmode \unskip\unskip \par \fi
         \if@newlist \if@nobreak \@nbitem \else
                        \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
                        \addvspace\@topsep \addvspace{-\parskip}\fi
           \else \addpenalty\@itempenalty \addvspace\itemsep
          \fi
    \global\@inlabeltrue
\fi
\everypar{\global\@minipagefalse\global\@newlistfalse
          \if@inlabel\global\@inlabelfalse \hskip -\parindent \box\@labels
             \penalty\z@ \fi
          \everypar{}}\global\@nobreakfalse
\if@noitemarg \@noitemargfalse \if@nmbrlist \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi \fi
\sbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#1}}%
\global\setbox\@labels
 \hbox{\unhbox\@labels \hskip \itemindent
       \hskip -\labelwidth \hskip -\ALC@tlm
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
                \box\@tempboxa
          \else \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}\fi
       \hskip \ALC@tlm}\ignorespaces}
%
\newenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{
\let\@item\ALC@item
  \newcommand{\ALC@lno}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}
{{\footnotesize \arabic{ALC@line}:}}{}%
}
\let\@listii\@listi
\let\@listiii\@listi
\let\@listiv\@listi
\let\@listv\@listi
\let\@listvi\@listi
\let\@listvii\@listi
  \newenvironment{ALC@g}{
    \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{ \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@
    \listparindent\z@ \rightmargin\z@ 
    \topsep\z@ \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@\parsep\z@
    \leftmargin 1em
    \addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}
    }
  }
  {\end{list}}
  \newcommand{\ALC@it}{\addtocounter{ALC@line}{1}\addtocounter{ALC@rem}{1}\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}\item}
  \newcommand{\ALC@com}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{default}}%
{}{\ \algorithmiccomment{##1}}}
  \newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}
  \newcommand{\ENSURE}{\item[\algorithmicensure]}
  \newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}
  \newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\algorithmiccomment{##1}}
%changes by alex smola
  \newcommand{\INPUT}{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
  \newcommand{\OUTPUT}{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}
  \newcommand{\SET}{\item[\algorithmicset]}
%  \newcommand{\TRUE}{\algorithmictrue}
%  \newcommand{\FALSE}{\algorithmicfalse}
  \newcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand}
  \newcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor}
  \newenvironment{ALC@func}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@main}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
%end changes by alex smola
  \newenvironment{ALC@if}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@for}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@whl}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@loop}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@rpt}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \renewcommand{\\}{\@centercr}
  \newcommand{\IF}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\SHORTIF}[2]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##1\
    \algorithmicthen\ {##2}}
  \newcommand{\ELSE}[1][default]{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelse%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\ELSIF}[2][default]%
{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelsif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\FOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\FORALL}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\SHORTFORALL}[2]{\ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ ##1\ %
    \algorithmicdo\ {##2}}
  \newcommand{\WHILE}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicwhile\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@whl}}
  \newcommand{\LOOP}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@loop}}
%changed by alex smola
  \newcommand{\FUNCTION}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfunction\ ##2\ %
    \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@func}}
  \newcommand{\MAIN}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicmain\ ##2\ %
    \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@main}}
%end changed by alex smola
  \newcommand{\REPEAT}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat%
    \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@rpt}}
    \newcommand{\UNTIL}[1]{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicuntil\ ##1}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}
    \newcommand{\ENDFUNCTION}{\end{ALC@func}}
    \newcommand{\ENDMAIN}{\end{ALC@main}}
  }{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicendif}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}\ALC@it\algorithmicendwhile}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}
    \newcommand{\ENDFUNCTION}{\end{ALC@func}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfunction}
    \newcommand{\ENDMAIN}{\end{ALC@main}\ALC@it\algorithmicendmain}
  } 
  \renewcommand{\@toodeep}{}
  \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{\setcounter{ALC@line}{0}\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}%
      \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent\z@%
      \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
      \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}
      {\labelwidth 0.5em }
      {\labelwidth  1.2em }
      \leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
      \ALC@tlm\labelsep
      }
    }
  {\end{list}}
```